# Using Virtual Servers for Backups

Tags: windows, active-directory, webserver, dhcp, backups

I have three server machines inbound and I have hosted following services on them

1. Active Directory
2. DHCP
3. DNS
4. File Server
5. Web Server

I have access to a virtual server too. I want to ask how wise it would be to use that Virtual server for backups in disaster recovery point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is definitely a good way to backup your data backup on VMs, however you have question of size of your storage where you keep your backups.
More importantly you can go for snapshot options for Vms and bare metal recovery for physical windows Vms.

I hope the answer will be useful..Thanks..